# Backward Compatibility for VBA between 2010 and 365

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have an issue where I utilize the Microsoft Project object library in VBA on my machine that has Project 365 installed. When I try to run the macro on a machine that has project 2010 on it this library is not available. I have gone through the tools reference to find the appropriate library unsuccessfully. Does anyone have an idea?

I have tried recoding some of the code (which is run in Excel) that attempts to open the Microsoft project item. However when I go to the other machine when I attempt to run the code it dies immediately when i try to `Dim t task`

```
Dim PrjApp      As MSProject.Application
Dim aProg       As MSProject.Project
Dim PrjFullName As String
Dim t           As Task
```

Comment: Does it work if you late-bind instead? i.e. remove the reference to MS Project object library, then change all MS Project object declarations to `As Object`, replace any/all Project constants inline with their underlying value (or re-declare them and leave usages alone). FWIW `Dim` statements aren't executable, the error would be at compile-time.

Comment: Early-bound references have a tendency to be flaky when used across versions. You can try early-binding by referencing the earliest version you need to support (2010), and not using any features that exist in the later versions. Late-bound code that uses features that exist in 365 but not in 2010, will blow up at run-time either way.

Comment: `t` should be declared as `MSProject.Task`. Additionally, are you able to set a reference to the MS Project Object model in your excel vba code? It should be listed as "Microsoft Project 14.0 Object Library" (or something very similar).

Comment: Thank you all, the late binding solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just doing it in VBA then I would just do this:

```
Dim PrjApp      As Application
Dim aProg       As Project
Dim PrjFullName As String
Dim t           As Task
```

I have written a ton of VBA in Project across versions going back to almost the beginning and have never had this issue.